Freestanding Patio Cover Beam Size
Trying to build something like this but with a 16ft span: https://www.backyarddiscovery.com/collections/slope-roof-gazebos/products/12-x-9-5-arcadia-gazebo
I'd like to build a slope roof patio cover with a footprint of 16 x 9. I'd like to have 4 6x6 posts? What size beam would I need to span 16 feet? Would 2-2x8s screwed together for each beam be enough support? I'll notch the post 1-1/2 inches and use a joist tie for the outside 2x8.  I'm thinking of using a lightweight polycarbonate or tin for the roofing material. Rear posts will be 9 ft tall and front posts will be 8ft tall. Midwest location. 

Midwest you need to know the local snow load.  Your local building department can give you the best answers.  Is it a total of four post for the whole area/at each corner or four posts per beam?

I am thinking the 2x8's will sag at a 16' span- just from their own weight.
